# random sample of two 100X100 multidimensional arrays, with same row no. in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, random, numpy-ndarray

I have two multidimensional array(matrix) in numpy, one being the training set(100,100 dimension) and other being the class label(100X1 dimension) I want to take random samples using np.random.choice but don't know how to figure out taking the same row no. from both matrices.

for eg.,

```
k=np.random.choice(10,replace=False)
temp_data=data.ix[k]
temp_datat=datat.ix[k]
```

would this work for sampling 10 same random rows from both my arrays data and datat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach to what was suggested by @Umang Gupta and may be helpful if you also want to keep track of those not selected

```
# Suppose X_train is your 100 x 100 dataset
# and y_train is your array of labels
idx = np.arange(len(X_train))
np.shuffle(idx)

NUM_SAMPLES = 50
sampled_idxs = idx[:NUM_SAMPLES]
rest_idxs = idx[NUM_SAMPLES:]

X_samples = X_train[sampled_idxs]
X_rest = X_train[rest_idxs]
y_samples = y_train[sampled_idxs]
y_rest = y_train[rest_idxs]
```

If you already have Scikit-Learn installed, you can use [test_train_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import test_train_split
X_samples, X_rest, y_samples, y_rest = train_test_split(X_train, y_train,
                                                        train_size=NUM_SAMPLES,
                                                        random_state=123)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the awesome [`numpy.random.randint()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) for achieving this. A complete working example is as follows:

```
# toy data
In [29]: train_set = np.random.random_sample((100, 100))

# of course, class labels have to be discrete :)
In [30]: class_label = np.random.random_sample((100, 1))

# number of samples that need to be picked (a.k.a batch_size)
In [31]: num_samples = 5

# generate sample indices in the range of 100
In [32]: sample_idxs = np.unique(np.random.randint(train_set.shape[0], size=num_samples))

In [33]: sample_idxs
Out[33]: array([24, 30, 37, 73, 74])

# index into the array to get the actual entries
In [34]: (train_set[sample_idxs]).shape
Out[34]: (5, 100)

# index into the class_label array to get the corresponding label entries    
In [35]: (class_label[sample_idxs]).shape
Out[35]: (5, 1)
```

---

There might be one caveat though. You might not sample the whole dataset even after multiple runs. Also, it's possible that the same example might be used in more than one training run.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a random choice and pick the same row?

Some thing like,

```
k = np.random.choice(100, 10, replace=True)
row1 = arr1[k]
row2 = arr2[k]
```

This will work for 10 rows. First argument is number to pick from (0-99, both inclusive) and second is number of elements to pick.

Comment: k=np.random.choice(i,replace=False)
        temp_data=data.ix[k]
        temp_datat=datat.ix[k]

Comment: Yes, if I understand your problem correctly. @shivamthakur I updated as per new description